# TFS 2010 branching model for an in-house application

Tags: tfs, branching-strategy

This is not a question where I don't have any ideas, but instead I would like to present a model and see if it gets approved or anyone can see issues with it or has  better suggestions. They say it's better to carefully choose you branching model in order to avert future headaches.

So we have an in-house application with only one version (the latest) released to the customers and basically there are 2 kind of development activities: the main activity is working for the next release and usually includes new features and corrective fixes and it is planned, and the second one which is not planned and is about maintenance and includes hotfixes of the current version in production.

After long research we decided to go with a **Main** trunk from which we branch-out 2 child branches: **Development** & **Maintenance** (or **Hotfix**). As it is presented in the guide, the daily development would happen in the **Development** branch from where we do reverse integration (RI) everytime we have features ready for the next release. Right before the release the reverse integration will stop and the code will be stabilized in the **Main** branch. After the release from **Main** there will be a forward integration (FI) from **Main** to **Development** and **Maintenance**.

Any hotfix will happen in **Maintenance** only and depending on the fix (for example if we want to retain it in the codebase) we will do a RI into **Main** and from there a FI into **Development**.

Now everything looks all right, at least on paper, so I would like to hear others' opinions on this model.

For example we would also considering having another branch, **Release**, where the stabilizing of the code happens before a release to production (instead of working directly in **Main**) and of course we will release from here to production and do a RI into **Main** followed by a FI to **Development** & **Maintenance**, but we're not sure if this will bring any benefit or will just increase the complexity?

And assuming that there will be features in **Development** that won't be ready or not desired for the next release this means we will have to do some "cherry picking" of the changesets that are related to the wanted features, but that's not too good according to the docs. Any suggestions?

Again I know it's not a simple, straightforward question but instead an open one, still I hope to hear from anybody with a similar experience. Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245304/branching-plan-required/3246496#3246496

Comment: @KMoraz: What I could extract from the other post is to choose simple & wisely, and I like that. However, I am not sure that only Dev & Main is enough for us. We need to isolate the work on hotfixes between releases. Thanks for the link, all the reading I can get helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read the TFS ALM Rangers Branching Guidance documentation?  What you are proposing looks pretty much like their "Standard Branch Plan", though they encourage having both a release and "service pack" branch (much like your Release and Maintenance branches above).

http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/

I've implemented the Standard Branching plan at a few clients and haven't had a problem with it.  If you plan to adopt concurrent streams of work (feature crews, etc) the Branching Guidance has solid plans for that as well.

Another thing to consider might be a stair-step model where you create new Dev branches at each release and freeze the old one as a release.  This would avoid RIs since you can just Hotfix the old one and FI the fix to the new Dev branch if necessary.  I've worked in this model as well and it was awesome.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I downloaded the content from the codeplex site, although I didn't read everything, skipped the multi-team, multi-features, concurent service packs etc. Yeap the Standard Branch Plan looks good, although we don't really do Service Packs (cumulative hotfixes/patches) so probably having Realease and Hotfix branches would be enough. Nevertheless I could not find in any of the guides some in deep explanations related to this plan; like when to do FI & RI, where to stabilize the code before a production release, what branch gets released to, where and at what point in time.

Comment: yeah they don't give you everything...  That's what consultants are for ;)  ...  Actually I think it's because the answers to those questions are kind of qualitative/subjective.   In my experience, the answer is "whatever works for your team".  In the past I've worked on teams where RI's to Main only happen when you want to branch for a release and other teams have done it whenever a feature is ready for QA.  I'd always recommend raising the bug bar pretty high once you are in a Release branch.  P1/S1 bugs only.  All other stabilization should happen somewhere before that.